# Node MySQL bulk insert with a sub query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqljs

Is it possible with the node mysql library to bulk insert using a sub query?

Something like

```
var data = [[1,2],[3,4]];

var qry = 'insert into tableA select ? from tableB where id = ?';

connection.query(qry,[data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the column on insert and match that column to the sub query.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2)
SELECT column3, column4
FROM Table2 AS t2
WHERE t2.id = ?;
```